# How many bytes does date datatype occupy in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

How many bytes does date datatype occupy in oracle?

```
v_date:=to_date('15-08-2014','dd-mm-yyyy');
v_day:=to_char(v_day,'day');
```

now blank space is padded at the end of v_day,so the below condition wont work

```
if v_day='saturday' then
dbms_ouput.put_line('half_day');
```

for the above condition to work,i need to use rtim

```
v_day:=rtrim(to_char(v_day,'day'));
```

now the question is to know How many bytes does date datatype occupy in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with how many bytes the data type occupies. By default [the `day` format model is padded to the length of the longest day name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF) in the session language (based on NLS settings).

> The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name, or the longest abbreviated day name, respectively, among valid names determined by the values of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and NLS_CALENDAR parameters.

You can change that by adding the `FM` format modifier:

```
v_date:=to_date('15-08-2014','dd-mm-yyyy');
v_day:=to_char(v_day,'FMday');
if v_day='saturday' then
  dbms_ouput.put_line('half_day');
...
```

The day name itself is NLS-dependent though, in long and abbreviated form, so if the session could be in a different language you should make sure `to_char` is using English as the date language.

Comment: To quote from the manual, "Oracle Database uses its own internal format to store dates. Date data is stored in fixed-length fields of seven bytes each, corresponding to century, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second". A literal reading of this would seem to indicate that a DATE takes up 49 bytes (seven fields of seven bytes each), but I suspect the wording above is awkward and that a DATE actually occupies only seven bytes (giving a range of 256 centuries, or 25600 years). [Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413)

Share and enjoy.)